# What is the purpose of using translatable in Android strings?

Tags: android, string

What does the `translatable` attribute, like `translatable="false"`, mean?

Answer (score 45):

This attribute points out that this attribute will be the same for all locales. Why is it useful?

1. The localization files are more readable for human and saves time.
2. It tells the Lint tool that everything is fine and that Android does not need to look for this resource translation.

Full explanation:
http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings

So, generally, this means if don't put this attribute, you should always localize this resource, otherwise tell people and compiler that this is unique for all locales by specifying this attribute.

Comment: OK, what about strings that *may* be translated, but don't *need* to be translated? E.g. a logo which will be the same in most languages, but might be different in some.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: Nope. Simplest solution is to disable the lint error that triggers on missing translations. Less than ideal. Maybe the best solution is to simply copy the string untranslated unto all the locales, and hope that proguard has the brains to combine them all into one string at optimization time.

Comment: yeah it was very annoying before - I should have copy-paste not translatable strings to all xml files so lint would not stop building app, but now using this it became much easier

Comment: As a translator, I shouldn't translate strings with this attribute, right? Should I copy the string from strings.xml to my locale (values-zh-rTW/strings.xml) or ignore it completely?

Comment: @cges30901 ignore it completely

Answer (score 29):

If you are supporting multiple languages, and there are some strings which should not be translated (that means same across all languages) then you can use **translatable="false"**

For ex: Numbers`<string name="account_setup_imap" translatable="false">IMAP</string>`

[Detailed Description](http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings)

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of that attribute, but apparently (now) there's a reason for using it: see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/40j7eSoRmAs) from ADT-Dev google group.

BTW, I just tried it and it works in fixing those Android Lint errors.

Answer (score -3):

I don't see any reference to that in official docs, however, it probably is just an indicator for humans looking at the file that that particular string entity should not be translated.

If you have an Android app that you wish to internationalize, a common tactic is to just send your strings.xml file to translators.  So that attribute would just be a flag for them.